# Is there something like a vision paper in mathematics?

Tags: journals

I spoke with a computer scientist a few weeks who told me that in computer science there is something called a "vision paper", which is a paper that does not contain concrete results, but rather outlines a more general vision of what one either wants to do, or how a field may develop etc. A *future vision* in any case is presented.
Searching the internet "vision paper" for computer science actually did not return many results - lest so for mathematics.

But maybe there do exist such journals that offer a home for such articles in mathematics and it just happened that I didn't find that. If you know of any, please let me know. The journal doesn't exclusively have to publish vision papers (actually, I think that would be bad, since it would probably be soon filled with all kinds of fantasies regarding how some subfields of mathematics might develop), but should *also* allow such papers. There are some journals that allow papers containing open problems and conjectures. I am looking for something a bit broader than that, where a vision of a field can be presented that is extrapolated from the current state.

I am interested because I myself am about to write such an article, and I'm not sure where to best post it. On a blog? I'd like to make it citeable and everything that purely online may vanish at some point in time (e.g. the blog providing company may shut down). A paper solely in arXiv? Would be an opportunity, but perhaps lacks in credentials.

Comment: I remember seeing a relevant question in this site...

Comment: @PraphullaKoushik: I wonder if you are thinking about https://mathoverflow.net/questions/268482/publishing-conjectures ? From an answer there, maybe [Arnold Math Journal](http://www.springer.com/mathematics/journal/40598) is what is sought.

Comment: @WillieWong This journal only allows conjectures; I'm looking for something a bit broader than that, something where a vision for a field can be presented (this is related to automated theorem proving), which is not necessarily tied to some concrete open problems.

Comment: @user43263: did you look at the Aim/Scope of the Arnold Math Journal I mentioned? I think it is somewhat broader than "just conjectures".

Comment: @WillieWong No, not that.. the question I am trying to remember is not about conjectures.. It is about results that authors claim to have proof but as a "trailer of a movie" they release a paper that gives main results in the upcoming paper...

Comment: Not answering your question about journals, but rather the question in the title: According to _Récoltes et Semailles,_ Grothendieck considers his _Pursuing Stacks_ as some sort of "vision paper" or, as he calls it, a "rêve éveillé".

Comment: @WillieWong I mean https://mathoverflow.net/questions/307619/properties-of-a-research-announcement

Comment: Usually "vision papers" are more likely to appear as conference proceedings than in a journal. Even authors with high gravitas/status tend to go this route.

Comment: @WillieWong You are right that it is broader than "just conjectures" (that was a bit off hand from myself). The AMJ seems to fit in with what I have in mind in terms of interdisciplinarity and informal understanding, but less in terms that articles should  "'unhide' the process of mathematical discovery". So it seems that a *concrete* result or problem should be at the core of the article, where as in my case it's general vision of where something might be moving towards. This does seem to be outside the scope of the journal, since there is no "unhiding" of the research process to be done.

Comment: @MyNinthAccount @ WillieWong Perhaps the AMS Notices is also a good places? Following various links that were mentioned I ended up at http://www.ams.org/publications/notices/noticesauthors which mentions that it publishes "articles that report on major new developments in mathematics" among many other different types of articles. Because it allows such a variety of articles, perhaps this might be the best places to try to submit. Can anyone confirm if this is a good idea?

Comment: Or are there any "hidden" things that I have to keep in mind, that they don't mention in the *Information for Notices Authors* section (such as, e.g., one has to be a member of the AMS to have the article accepts, or to be already well-known research)?

Comment: If you have identified some specific journals, I would suggest just emailing the editors and ask whether what you have in mind is on topic.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The "mother of all vision papers", the [Langlands program,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langlands_program) was simply a [handwritten letter;](http://publications.ias.edu/sites/default/files/handwritten-ltw.pdf) so I would not worry too much about "where to post it", it's the content that will determine the impact.

For archival and citation purposes you could see if arXiv accepts it, and otherwise you could upload it on [Zenodo](https://zenodo.org): that will give you a DOI, and you can update the paper (the DOI will always point to the latest version). Zenodo is backed by CERN, so it should be a secure repository.

Comment: In the first paragraph, regarding Langland's program, I'm afraid you are falling trap to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survivorship_bias regarding the way the Langlands program was announced. Nice way to put it though, the "mother of all vision papers" :)

Comment: Another interpretation of the Langlands program is that what matters (in addition to content) is who it is sent to - in this case, Weil. If a vision is, for instance, the suggestion that mathematicians should attack a certain set of problems using certain methods, then the really important thing is to get it into the hands of mathematicians who know those methods - potentially personally or by giving talks, rather than by publishing. In this case even if it is published in a suitable venue, if the venue is not read by these mathematicians, the effect will be small.